# insert data from different db server every second

Tags: sql-server

Primary DB have all the raw data every 10 minutes,  but it only store for 1 week. I would like to keep all the raw data for 1 year in another DB, and it is different server. How can it possible?

I have created T-query to select the required data from Primary DB.  How can it keep update the data from primary DB and insert to secondary DB accordingly? The table has Datetime, would it able to insert new data for latest datetime?

Notes: source data SQL 2012
secondary db SQL 2005

Comment: look into `Log shipping`, `Replication` or if you are on SQL Server 2012 or later version look into `Always on Availability groups`.

Comment: Always include your sql server version info -- sql keeps changing. Lots of the enhancements have significant performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on sql2008 or higher the [merge command (ms docs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx) may be very useful in your actual update process. Be sure to you understand it.

You table containing the full year data sounds like it could be OLAP, so I refer to it that way occasionally (if you don't know what OLAP is, look it up sometime, but it does not matter to this answer)

If you are only updating 1 or 2 tables, log shipping replication and failover may not work well for you, especially since you are not replicating the table due to different retention policies if nothing else. So make sure you understand how replication, etc. work before you go down that path. If these tables are over perhaps 50% of the total database, log shipping style methods might still be your best method. They work well and handle downtime issues for you -- you just replicate the source database to the OLAP server and then update from the duplicate database into your OLAP database.

Doing an update this every second is an unusual requirement. However, if you create a linked server, you be able to insert your selected rows into a staging table on the remote sever and them update from them to your OLAP table(s).  If you can reliably update your OLAP table(s) on the remote server in 1 second, you have a potentially useful method. If not, you may fall behind on posting data to your OLAP tables. If you can update once a minute, you may find you are much less likely to fall behind on the update cycle (at the cost of being slightly less current at all times).

You want to consider putting after triggers on the source table(s) that copies the changes to a staging table (still on the source database) into staging table(s) with an identity on this staging table along with a flag to indicate Insert, Update or Delete and you are well positioned to ship updates for one or a few tables instead of the whole database. You don't need to requery your source database repeatedly to determine what data needs to be transmitted, just select top 1000 from from your staging table(s) (order by the staging id) and move them to the remote staging table.

If your fall behind, a top 1000 loop keeps from trying to post to much data in any one cross server call.

Depending on your data, you may be able to optimize storage and reduce log churn by not copying all columns to your staging table, just the staging id and the primary key of the source table and pretend that whatever data is in the source record at the time you post it to the OLAP database accurately reflects the data at the time the record was staged. It won't be 100% accurate on your OLAP table at all times, but it will be accurate eventually.

Cannot over emphasize that you need to accommodate the downtime in your design -- unless you can live with data loss or just wrong data. Even reliable connections are not 100% reliable.